# Configure Apache to redirect 404 errors to a location based on the requested path

Tags: apache-2.2

Right now I have the following in my httpd.conf file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
```

This works but I need an additional rule that will handle my debug path as well. For example, if I request

```
http://www.mypage.com/debug/page-that-does-not-exist.html
```

I want it to redirect to:

```
/debug/index.html
```

Instead of the index in my document root. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Directory /debug>
    ErrorDocument 404 /debug/index.html
</Directory>
```

Comment: I had to use the full path for the directory, but that did the trick! Talk about over-thinking it, I was looking into using mod rewrite haha. Thanks!